# Coloring Text in the .tex file Prior to Rendering It

Tags: color, winedt

I was wondering if there's a way to change color of words or passages in the raw tex document itself, prior to rendering it into pdf? Thanks.

Comment: @percusse, sure, by all means. How can I do that?

Comment: @Forgiver, I'm using Winedt. Do you think it's possible to do it with that editor?

Comment: Any [TeX editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors) should be able to do  this... *apparently* [WinEdt can, too.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinEdt)

Comment: You can go through [the list of your older questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11802/ganzewoort?tab=questions) and click on the checkmarks next to the answers that address your concerns.

Comment: What is explained in the manual is how to change color of the rendered text. Where does the manual give an answer to the question I am asking here?

Comment: Did that, like I said. Where (what section) in the FAQ is the explanation?

Comment: Yes, I have. What section in that link gives the answer?

Comment: Then, maybe I should move on to another editor. Would you recommend any?

Comment: I use TeXnicCenter 1 RC. There is no sophisticated features (not even what you are looking for) but it is enough for me!

Comment: I suggest you to close this question and make another one asking which editor provide features you want. Please mention the features in more detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed WinEdt and I confirm that there is no such a feature.